Cannot change Apple Account info on web but there is no device logged in to iCloud
This feels like a feature gap: A device logged in to my Apple Account for use in only App Store is treated a trusted device, but it cannot be used to alter Apple Account information.
Note that this is a different question from How to change Apple Account password on web when Stolen Device Protection is on and my only Apple device is stolen?, which is in a different scenario.
Context: A user can choose to log in to different Apple Accounts for iCloud and App Store. The benefit is that the user can then purchase apps that are available in different countries and have them installed on one device.
In this case, I don't have any device that is logged in to iCloud using this Apple Account. However, when I try to update my Apple Account info on the web, it prompts me with the Stolen Device Protection warning message below. Specifically, I want to:

Remove the current primary email address and use another verified email address as the primary email address.
Remove trusted devices that are no longer logged in to App Store using this Apple Account.
Update Apple Account password.

Warning message is as follows:

Because Stolen Device Protection is turned on, some of your account information can’t be changed on the web. To change your password, use your other Apple devices.

There are a couple of devices listed in Trusted Devices and I can see them on the Apple Account web page. These devices highly likely got added because I previously/currently logged in to App Store on those devices using this Apple ID. I am pretty sure that I never logged in to any of those devices using iCloud.
However, I cannot "update my Apple Account info" on those devices either:
When I tried to access my Apple Account on a device that is logged in to App Store using this Apple Account by going to App Store settings and "view my account", it just redirected me to the web log in page on the device using Safari, and then I logged in, it gave me the same warning message above when I tried to update anything.
How am I supposed to update my account info, without having to spare a device to actually use this Apple Account for iCloud?

I don't want to log out of iCloud on my device that is currently logged in to some other Apple Account and log in using this Apple Account, because that might cause data to be replicated across my accounts.
I do not want to wipe my device just for this purpose.
Obviously, I do not want to buy a new device just for this purpose.


Update 1
Regarding the suggestion in the comment to borrow another device: A device newly signed in to the Apple Account cannot be used to alter Apple Account information either! It seems like I need to stay logged in for at least a week or more to gain access. I don't know who is going to lend me a device for this purpose. If there is any better solution it would be appreciated.

Ooh - be careful with your next steps. I would probably spend time with Apple support to confirm your options for recovering control on the assumption that you can borrow another device if needed (or rent one or get something used) to regain control.

I cannot update my Account info if I newly signed into some device using this Apple Account, so it sounds like if I really borrow one, I need to borrow it for at least a couple of weeks. Never heard that Apple provides such services but I think I can check with support, though I never had useful answer from them before.

Please don’t take offense. It seems you understand precisely what is required and have evaluated it as too much effort or too costly to compily with the terms and steps required for service?

"It seems you understand precisely what is required and have evaluated it as too much effort or too costly to compily with the terms and steps required for service?" -> Correct.

"Please don’t take offense." -> I did not. Thanks.

Awesome, there are some amazing people here with tons of experience - I’m looking forward to learning if there’s a non-obvious fix for you here.

Thank you for your attention @bmike. I will update here if I later learn about anything by myself regarding this issue. Agree that there are some workarounds. Worst case scenario I can take your advice on borrowing a device maybe.
